# what is fastest way to draw chartjs charts

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have a lot of charts I need to draw with a huge amount of data on bobble plots.

I wonder what is the **fastest** and the most efficient way to plot them using chartjs. 
I made the dots smaller, yet it still takes 5 sec to load the page.

Comment: determine exactly what part of the process is causing the (perceived) delay. Is it the rendering process? is it the retrieval of data? is it jquery being a pig?

Answer (score 0):

A couple things come to mind:

1. I would check that nothing else on your page is slowing your load times.
2. If chart.js is the issue due to the high number of dots, do you need every data point entered? Could you do every other? I'm not sure what your data is, but if you're just looking at trends, this might work for you.